# Gliderjs Horizontal Bar class

Tags: html, css, carousel

I'm working with GliderJs and it all seems okay except for the one horizontal bar that comes. I can't seem to find the class (so I can hide it). Anyone know which class it belongs to or what I can do to hide it?

[This is what the implementation looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l34GF.png) and i'd like to remove that bar at the bottom.

My code looks like

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    draggable: false,
    dots: ".dots",
    rewind: true,
    arrows: {
      prev: ".glider-prev",
      next: ".glider-next"
    },
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js"></script>

<div class="glider-contain">
  <div class="glider">
    <div style="color: black;">your content here</div>
    <div>your content here</div>
    <div>your content here</div>
  </div>

  <button aria-label="Previous" class="glider-prev">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
  </button>
  <button aria-label="Next" class="glider-next">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dots"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this turns out to be a known Firefox Browser issue.
[Solution from the Repository](https://github.com/NickPiscitelli/Glider.js#native-scrollbars)